# Получать данные из адресной книги, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Делала все, как сказано в статье и даже учебнике *"Разработка и продажа программ для iPhone и iPad"*.
Ссылка на статью: http://touchdev.ru/shorts/912.
И так, сама проблема заключается в том, что не видит что такое: picker, salf. Сам код:

```
- (IBAction) onButtonBrowse:(id)sender
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
    [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init]; picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release]; 
}
```

Ругается на

```
...= self;
[ self ...];
[picker ...];
```

Добавила все что сказанно в статье, но все равно ругается, импортировала

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```

Скриншот отрывка кода:
http://hkar.ru/jFmK

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, статья древняя и наверняка что-то изменилось с тех пор, поэтому слепо копировать и вставлять будет как минимум то что Вы имеете сейчас.

Во-вторых, учитесь работать с документацией.

В-третьих, описание ошибок в XCode довольно информативно, и можно понять из них что там не так.

Теперь по существу:

*picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;*
Что там за ошибку выдал XCode? Наверняка, что объект не того типа?
Обратимся к [документации](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPeoplePickerNavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) и выясним, что **picker.peoplePickerDelegate** может принимать объект типа **ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate**, а self у Вас это UIViewController, если я е ошибаюсь? Стало быть как минимум в класс нужно добавить **ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate** и реализовать его методы.

Следующая ошибка:  *[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];*
Сначала посмотрим что там XCode выдал? Наверное что метод уже не используется. Что мы делаем? Снова ныряем в [документацию](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html). И оказывается, что нужно использовать **presentViewController:animated:completion:**

И последняя ошибка:  [picker release]; 
Если Ваш проект использует ARC, то нельзя в ручную заниматься управлением объектов в памяти. И об этом XCode тоже написал в описании ошибки.

Comment: Хорошо, можете тогда пожалуйста дать новую статью про то, как открывать контакты с приложения? Я смотрела в книге:
Елисеев В.Д. -  Разработка и продажа программ для iPhone и iPad.
181 страничка, забейте книгу в гугле, она в открытом доступе 10мб весит.

Или скачайте отсюда:
http://padabum.com/x.php?id=43114

Comment: Книга старая как г. мамонта - можете в нее смело не смотреть. А ваш код еще можно исправить. Я же написал как это сделать вроде. Там добавить, здесь убрать, кое что изменить! В чем трудности? Я не могу дать полноценное решение, так как я не видел всего кода.

Вот тут рабочий вариант: [туториал][1]

[1]:http://ioscreator.com/retrieving-contacts-from-the-address-book/